# How to translate this PostgreSQL command into Ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I want to create a user and a database in PostgreSQL 9.6 via Ansible.

In the shell I did it this way:
sudo -u postgres createuser -S -D -R -P ckan_default
createdb -O ckan_default ckan_default -E utf-8

I'm running everything out of Ansible Tower.

What I have tried is, with a variety of options, like removing become and become_user:

```
- name: Create postgres user 
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    name: "ckan_default"
    password: "ckan_default"
    role_attr_flags: NOCREATEDB, NOCREATEROLE, NOSUPERUSER

- name: Create DB
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: ckan_default
    encoding: UTF-8
    owner: ckan_default
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": true,
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_postgresql_db_payload_FsaEtw/__main__.py\", line 421, in main\n    db_connection = psycopg2.connect(database=maintenance_db, **kw)\n  File \"build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/psycopg2/__init__.py\", line 126, in connect\n    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)\nOperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user \"postgres\"\n\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ssl_rootcert": null,
            "ssl_mode": "prefer",
            "target": "",
            "encoding": "UTF-8",
            "login_user": "postgres",
            "login_host": "",
            "target_opts": "",
            "db": "ckan_default",
            "lc_ctype": "",
            "owner": "",
            "port": 5432,
            "login_unix_socket": "",
            "state": "present",
            "template": "",
            "login_password": "",
            "maintenance_db": "postgres",
            "lc_collate": "",
            "name": "ckan_default"
        }
    },
    "msg": "unable to connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user \"postgres\"\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not too far off: It turned out that /etc/sudoers had to be changed.

Line 2 and 4 were added. The **become: yes** was also not needed anymore.

```
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
{{ usr_name }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to set the become_pass variable to the password of user postgres (like postgres_password wich is set to vault_postgres_password which is stored in vault)

```
- name: Create postgres user 
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  become_pass: "{{ postgres_password }}"
  postgresql_user:
    name: "ckan_default"
    password: "ckan_default"
    role_attr_flags: NOCREATEDB, NOCREATEROLE, NOSUPERUSER
```

in file group_vars/my_postgres_hosts.yml :

```
postgres_password: "{{ vault_postgres_password }}"
```

in file group_vars/all/vault :

```
vault_postgres_password: "theReal-postgres-password-is-protected"
```

Also, look at this recent post :
[Ansible: Attach role to user in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671963/ansible-attach-role-to-user-in-postgres)